# Use PHP to remove content within shortcode tag outside of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a site where I am pulling in WordPress content and using it to display an excerpt. Since I am just pulling in the content, the caption shortcode is being pulled in with it.

Since I am working outside of WordPress, I am looking for a way to use PHP to remove any content that appears within a caption shortcode. So if I have this:

```
[caption id="456"]Content[/caption]
```

And it is within a `<p>` tag, I need to remove it without touching the rest of the content.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/L6SslM) example of the below code.

I believe you could use Regex and `preg_replace()` for this with the following pattern:

`/(\[caption\sid="\d+"\].*\[\/caption])/`

```
$pattern = '/(\[caption\sid="\d+"\].*\[\/caption])/';
$string = '<p>Something outside caption[caption id="456"]Content[/caption]</p>';

$captionRemoved = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

This would output:

`<p>Something outside caption</p>`

I'm under the impression you want to keep the `<p></p>` tags and anything else.

Any issues just let me know.